# strange firefox float positioning, works fine in chrome/safari (CSS)

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I'm having a weird issue in Firefox that I can't seem to fix. In both Chrome and Safari my float: left and float: right columns are working properly and in the right position, but when I view it in Firefox it's wayyyy messed up. My bottom header is in the section above it, and my columns are overlapping! I've been searching around but can't really find any concrete solutions to floating differences in Firefox -- can someone take a look at my code and tell me what's going on? Or does someone have any facts about Firefox floats that I'm not aware of? Thank you!

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRhB9/) with my code in it. The floaters seem to be okay in Firefox for the JsFiddle.. just not on my page. Ugh, I'll keep looking but I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the floats.. Removing them made everything align nicely on Firefox. At least the left column.

Here's the relevant float css:

```
.fourtextleft {
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: .5em;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    width: 38%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0% 5% 2% 0%;
    padding: 4% 2% 3.5% 0%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fourtextright {
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #666;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 3% 15% 2% 0%;
    padding: 4% 0% 3.5% 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.floaters {
    clear: both;
}
```

Thank you for any help you may provide!

ஃ Shanling

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem in this simple example, chances are it's got something to do with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the issue and it was a negative margin in one of the sections above the problem section. Seems that firefox doesn't like negative margins very much.. Thanks for the help guys :-)

Answer (score 6):

Without the issue being replicable it's hard to say what it is. However, just by reading the issue and from personal experiences I would say try adding `clear: both` to the fourth CSS class (your header). Additionally, it may not be necessary to float your second list to the right. Instead, set the margins once your first list is floating left.

Again, it's hard to say for sure if the issue can't be replicated. Just making educated guesses at this point. If you do find a way to replicate it, definitely bring it on back!

Answer (score 2):

Seem like IE should have had the problem not firefox, but hey if it works it works right?

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a layout of divs and I resolved my problem adding a white border to the divs using css, my sample code:

```
<head>
    <title>Sample Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divToLeft
        {
            width: 49.5%;
            float: left;
        }

        .divToRight
        {
            width: 49.5%;
            float: right;
        }
        .divToCenter
        {
            width: auto;
            float: none;
            **border-color: #FFF;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;**
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pnlMainHolder" style="width: 100%">

    <div id="Rep0" class="divToCenter">
    Rep0
    </div>
    <div id="pnlLeft" class="divToLeft">
        <div id="Rep1" class="divToCenter">
        rep1
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep3" class="divToCenter">
        rep3
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep5" class="divToCenter">
        rep5
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep7" class="divToCenter">
        rep7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pnlRight" class="divToRight">
        <div id="Rep2" class="divToCenter">
        rep2
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep4" class="divToCenter">
        rep4
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep6" class="divToCenter">
        rep6
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="Rep8" class="divToCenter">
        rep8
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Rep9" class="divToCenter">
    rep9
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

add `clear:both` for container and div's, it will solve your problem

```
.fourtextleft, .fourtextright, .floaters {
clear: both;
}
```